# UILabel does not show in UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a Done button and a Label on UIToolbar, but only the Done button is shown up. Here is my code:

```
func addDoneBtnAndCountLabelToKeyboard() {
    let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
    keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
    keyboardToolbar.isTranslucent = false
    keyboardToolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    //creating flexibleSpace
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(
        barButtonSystemItem: .done,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(CreateClubTVC.hideKeyboard)
    )

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "1"
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let addLabel = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: label)

    addButton.tintColor = UIColor.black

    keyboardToolbar.items = [addLabel, flexibleSpace,addButton]

    clubNameTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
    clubExplanationTV.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
}
```

I basically want the label.text to display the number of characters in  clubNameTextField, or clubExplanationTV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to finish setting up the label. You've created a label with no size.

If you want the label to just fit the text you assign to it, call `sizeToFit()` on the label after setting the label's `text`.